# How do I find a specific record with a params[] in a resulting query found using multiple joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have a complex query which successfully returns multiple records for a complete list.  This query contains LEFTJOINS including a LEFTJOIN to itself.   I  now am creating a report which needs to allow the selection of a specific record in the group.    I am having difficulty discovering how to form this request when there are multiple joins including left joins.   The returned parameter is in params[:search].   The query I am trying to use is:

```
@horses = Horse.find_by_sql["SELECT horses.id, horses.horse_name, horses.registration_number, horses.registration_number_2, horses.sire_name, horses.dam_name, horses_1.horse_name AS sire_name, horses_2.horse_name AS dam_name, horses.foaling_date, breeds.breed_name, colours.colour_name, genders.gender_name, owners.last_name, horses.arrival_date, horses.date_left, horses.notes FROM (((((horses LEFT JOIN horses AS horses_1 ON horses.sire_id = horses_1.id) LEFT JOIN horses AS horses_2 ON horses.dam_id = horses_2.id) LEFT JOIN breeds ON horses.breed_id = breeds.ID) LEFT JOIN colours ON horses.colour_id = colours.ID) LEFT JOIN genders ON horses.gender_id = genders.ID) LEFT JOIN Owners ON horses.owner_id = Owners.ID WHERE horses.id = ? ORDER BY horses.horse_name", params["search"]]
```

Updated after questions below:

There is no real advantage to listing the tables since the query works fine without the search parameter, in fact it is the query I use to produce the horse list.   Adding the params["search"] is causing the issue, I have confirmed that it  returns the correct value using debugger: params["search"] = 5, the intended id.

The error I get gives me a suggestion which is the same as I have done already. I just must be doing something really stupid that I just can't see.

Error Message: 
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) suggestion:  #   Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ?", start_date]

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Could you please show your tables ? Also, explain based on what you should be able to select the specific record

Comment: Do you mean a better way to pass the param to the `find_by_sql` method, or a better way to build your query?  The replacement parameter to the query is probably the *best* way to do this.  Regarding the overall complexity, it seems that if you have model relationships established, this should be a pretty straightforward one for an Arel query.

Comment: I have updated my question above which better explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is: There should have been a space between the "find_by_sql" and the "[".   When I put this space in, it works fine.